# Can I use Windows Containers to automate the provisioning of SQL Server Reporting Services instances?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I work on a mature SaaS web application that is integrated to a SQL Server Reporting Services VM in order to provide user reports.

We have found the need to more frequently provision new SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) instances to meet customer demand. I am hoping to be able to automate this as much as possible.

We've had issues with multiple SSRS instances on a single Windows Server VM not being sufficiently isolated from each other. Sometimes a seemingly innocuous configuration change on one SSRS instance brings down one or more of the others.

If we wanted to give each new SSRS instance its own dedicated Windows environment simply by adding new VMs, I am assuming that SQL Server and Windows licensing costs would quickly start to increase and become cost prohibitive.

Would Windows Containers give us the flexibility to automatically provision new SSRS instances in their own dedicated Windows environment, without incurring additional SQL and Windows licensing costs for each new container?

Comment: Did you end up going this route?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. I had hoped we would be doing more automation by now, but the application owner has just finsihed provisioning a fresh set of VMs with SSRS manually installed on them. I think containers are still a way off for their use of SSRS and I've lost touch with what the licensing implications are.

Comment: Thanks for the response I'm looking to do something similair for a reporting architecture that lives in containers

Comment: this may interest you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker

Comment: This is not a question about programming and would be better placed here: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would presumably work fine.   WinDocks is a docker container implementation on Windows Server 2012, and supports SQL Server 2008, 2012, and 2014.   We currently provide the database engine in containers, and this complies with MS licenses just fine . . . there's no reason the Reporting Services can't be used in containers in the same way.

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*

Comment: Thank you. So in your case, multiple SQL Server instances in dedicated containers on a single VM complies with licensing, but multiple SQL Server instances on separate dedicated VMs would not? Any chance you could point me to a web resource where Microsoft stipulates this?